# Comma joining a question and a quoted speech

Tags: commas, questions, quotations, comma-splices

I find this sentence in a paper:

> If this coming to awareness is true good luck, why would Shi Tiesheng need designer luck, he asks: “perhaps I’m already the darling of fate?”

Apparently, the author uses a comma to join two questions. One of the two questions is "why would Shi Tiesheng need designer luck", the other is a quotation introduced by "he asks". Therefore, the author appears to use a comma splice. A more grammatical version, I think, would be

> If this coming to awareness is true good luck, why would Shi Tiesheng need designer luck? He asks: “Perhaps I’m already the darling of fate?”

Do I correctly understand the sentence? Is the original sentence considered permissible?

Comment: Hello, thatness. I'd say that many would consider there to be some error here. Your suggestion is certainly grammatical, but one has to guess whether the writer would be satisfied. I'm not sure of the reasoning an attempt is being made to convey. << If this coming to awareness _is_ true good luck (he asks: “Perhaps I’m already the darling of fate?”), why would Shi Tiesheng need designer luck? >> clarifies, the parenthetical explaining why the protasis seems reasonable, but may not represent what the writer means. // Probably, this falls in the '[only] primarily opinion based [answers ...

Comment: will ensue]' category, which is why I've not submitted an 'answer'. I'll wait for other opinions before deciding whether or not to close-vote.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think that the question is answerable without opinon (the fact of the comma splice is based on fairly objective criteria), but I think that questions about straightforward comma splices are more appropriate for ELL than ELU. I don't really find anything of interest here for ELU's core audience.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan
  When a mistake is judged to have been made, except in the simplest of sentences guesswork is usually involved to decide what the author actually intended.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I agree that how to "fix" the sentence is largely a matter of opinion, but the crux of the question seems to me to be whether there's a mistake in the first place, and I think that that is more clear-cut.